# How is a non-interactive zero-knowlege proof constructed using homomorphic encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs

I've been reading too much, and I still haven't found the explaination I so crave. I'm looking specifically at zk-SNARKs, as implemented by ZCash. They say they use homomorphic encryption in their non-interactive, zero-knowledge proof systems, which I am just beginning to understand, but am very fascinated with.

I've encountered quite a bit of what appears to be infinitely confusing algebra in the explaination of these systems, and would like a more word of mouth based answer.

So, in layman's terms, how would one construct a non-interactive, zero-knowledge proof system using homomorphic encryption?

Comment: It sounds like the top-down approach of Ariel's series might be throwing you off a bit. You could try starting with an overview of elliptic curves and pairings, such as the final post in Ariel's series. His first few posts might be easier to follow if you know what concrete primitives are being used and understand their homomorphic properties, rather than having to imagine hypothetical primitives like HH.

Comment: It was all published by Zcash and others, and this is a very broad question. Did you make any progress, resulting in something specific?